# Escape All Special Characters on all Input Types of TEXT to Prevent XSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, plsql, special-characters, xss

Using jQuery, throughout my website based on what page is presented to the user, I would like to find all of the input text item selectors and escape all special characters in order to prevent cross site scripting.

Basically on load of a page or on submit, find all input types of "text", i.e.:

```
<input type="text" class="datepicker hasDatepicker form-control" id="START_DATE" name="s_date" maxlength="4000" size="30" value="" autocomplete="off">
```

and with jQuery, find and replace all special characters like:

```
</option<script>alert("XSS")</script>
```

to stop XSS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't rely on client side scripting to prevent cross site scripting from data initially present on the DOM.

You can in no way guarantee that the suspect code won't be executed before your's, yielding it ineffective. This should be done server-side, but you haven't indicated a language so I can't help there.

You can do this if you are bringing data in via AJAX and appending to the DOM, but that does not seem to be the case here. If AJAX is the case, you need not worry unless you are using `eval` or similar.

To provide an easy example, open JS console in this window and enter the following

```
$('input').val("<script>alert('derp');</script>");
```

You won't receive an alert, and the data is nicely appended into the search element at the top right of the screen. Just for kicks, you can try pure JS too:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value = "<script>alert('test');</script>";
```

Furthermore, if you are creating elements on the DOM with unsanitized data for some reason - you need to make sure that you are not simply concatenating strings to make them, but are instead creating the nodes correctly through JS (aka no jQuery `.html()`).

Comment: You *can't* rely on client-side code for sanitization.

Comment: Definitely bad choice of words on my part. Edited

Comment: Language is actually Oracle PL/SQL.

Comment: I'm not really sure how to help on PL/SQL in regards to generating a website unfortunately. You should update your question & tags with this information, and provide an example of the server-side code used to generate the input field - hopefully someone else can help. There is no safe way to pre-process your DOM with JavaScript.

Comment: All good Dave and appreciate your help. Just wanted to let you know that I will need to apply the following to all input fields within the site prior to be stored within the Oracle DB, i.e. : htf.escape_sc() on the server-side.

Comment: @tonyf - IMO storing sanitized data for display isn't necessarily the way to go either. You cannot guarantee that your display medium will always be HTML. Standard practice is to use the server-side escaping functions while creating the page. I'm not sure how str interpolation works in PL/SQL, but something like `<input value="${ htf.escape_sc() }" />`. Sorry I can't help more - hopefully that puts you on the right track :)